# Sails.js: Track logins

Tags: node.js, session, notifications, sails.js

I'm using Sails (0.11.0) and Passport (0.3.0) for a project. I can't figure out a way to log each login/logout activity.

From what I gather, this will probably require adding some code in the `login`/`connect` functions inside the `local` protocol or `passport` service, but I'm totally clueless about the specifics.

To avoid creating an xy problem, here's what I actually want to do: track the last logout time of a user so I can generate notifications for him/her on the next login (based on the activities that took place in the interim).

(Sure, I can work around the notification-collection procedure and probably maintain a cache of activities from subscribed sources per user, but I'd like to explore this way of doing it since it doesn't involve the storage overhead.)

Not sure if there's any relevant code I can share.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!